# Does Vala compiler use the -O3 flag by default?

Tags: gcc, optimization, vala

I tried, and it looks like Vala is passing the -O3 flag by default to the GCC compiler. Is that true? (my conclusion is based only on the size of the file when defining the-X flag to -O3 and without it)

Comment: GCC has an option to print all arguments passed to it

Comment: If you use `-v` with valac you cam see how vala calls `cc`

Comment: I was wrong, valac uses -O0.